# What does the notation $(\Re z)^{+}$ mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Context, problem 2.18 from Knuth et al's Concrete Mathematics:

Let $\Re z$ and $\Im z$ be the real and imaginary parts of the complex number $z$. The absolute value $|z|$ is $\sqrt{(\Re z)^2 + (\Im z)^2}$. A sum $\sum_{k\in K} a_k$ of complex terms $a_k$ is said to converge absolutely when the real-valued sums $\sum_{k\in K} \Re a_k$ and $\sum_{k\in K} \Im a_k$ both converge absolutely. Prove that $\sum_{k\in K} a_k$ converges absolutely if and only if there is a bounding constant B such that $\sum_{k\in F} |a_k| \le B$ for all finite subsets $F \subseteq K$.

Hint: Use the facts that $(\Re z)^{+} \leq |z|$, $(\Re z)^{-} \leq |z|$, $(\Im z)^{+} \leq |z|$, $(\Im z)^{+} \leq |z|$, and $|z| <= (\Re z)^{+} + (\Re z)^{-} + (\Im z)^{+} + (\Re z)^{-}$.

Funny enough I understood the problem and thought I knew how to attack it until I saw the hint, which I don't understand at all.

Note: I've no problem with the $\Re z$ part, it's the $^+$ part I don't know.

Comment: For $x\in \mathbb{R}\;\;\;x^{+}=\dfrac{|x|+x}{2},\;\;x^{-}=\dfrac{|x|-x}{2}.$ Then $x=x^{+}-x^{-}, \;\;|x|=x^{+}+x^{-}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when $x$ is any real number,
$$
x^+=\begin{cases}
x & x\ge 0\\
0 &  x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
x^-=\begin{cases}
0 & x\ge 0\\
-x &  x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
This means that $x=x^+-x^-$.